# Building Projects Failure

Tags: c#, build, publish

I'm having this problem last Friday when I'm trying to build my project to deploy it.
Whenever I build my project (Ctr+Shift+B or F6) I always encounter this kind of error.

[image]

When I'm trying to locate the file from my PC it looks like it reside in temporary folder and when building my project, this files automatically created.

[image]

Anyone encountered this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed `#region` statement (or perhaps some other syntax error) in the `.aspx` or `.cshtml` file that is generating that code.

Comment: I think it's tedious for me to do that, because i think each and every .cs files in my project has a corresponding App_Web_<something>. And also i would like to ask if visual studio generate this files at the first place?

Comment: @Rob: Those files are part of the ASP.Net compilation process and should be ignored.  You should be able to figure out which file it is from the generated code.

Comment: thanks slaks i think my teammates forgot to enclose #region with #endregion

Answer (score 0):

```
check if everything matches...
then use project properties to set properties of output exe.
Then use build solution to build the project.
You Will fine output exe in debug>bin folder
```